# Manual Installation of Jasper War on Weblogic

Tags: jasper-reports, weblogic12c

I'm installing jasper war manually on weblogic. jasper version 5.6, weblogic 12c and jdk1.7.
Followed exactly procedure mentioned in https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-install-guide/v561/procedure-installing-war-file-weblogic

Its giving  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'JasperServerDataBase'
I have selected target server. But still the above error is thrown.

Could anyone let me know what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jasper War manual installation on Weblogic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274919/jasper-war-manual-installation-on-weblogic)

Comment: Could anyone let me know what is wrong. Not able to find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a generic data source, with JNDI name "JasperServerDataBase". Put the parameters of the database where you created the JasperServer tables.

If your data source is already created, go to Monitoring -> Testing, and test it.